# the width of my div is fix while the content still overflow

Tags: html, css

i just want to ask about my html code here, i have a bit problem when it comes to sizing my div. when i set width of the div to 70px, the content still over flow the div, what i want is, the height of the div will automatically adjust when the content of it exceeds the width of the div.

any help?
heres my code. thanks in advance

```
<div class = "center"> the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.the quick brown fox jumps over the 
lazy dog.the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.the quick brown fox jumps 
over the lazy dog.the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.the quick brown 
fox jumps over the lazy dog.the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.the 
quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy 
dog.the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </div>

<style> .center{width:70px;} </style>
```

Comment: Make a code example at jsfiddle.net

Comment: Its working perfectly fine here: Check http://jsfiddle.net/4Emrm/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BQnae/ works perfect here

Comment: Should work fine. Did you try disabling/refreshing browser cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this css

```
.center
 {
    width:70px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

to force the browser to break words which would otherwise ecxeed the container.

Comment: oh men. thanks a lot, my problem solve. that's my very big problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The desired behavior you describe is the default behaviour ([proof](http://jsfiddle.net/v4KbN/)) - if it does not work that way, than there are some styles that interfere this beahviour, try to eliminate them.

Also, note that the `<style>` Tag needs to be placed in the head, it is not allowed in the body (well, to be precise - it is in HTML5 with the attribute `scoped` but atm this is very very poorly supported in the browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attribute to your CSS class

```
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: Better yet, `hidden`, Firefox usually adds scrollbars when it shouldn't in these cases.